# Intellij IDEA | Changelist, jump to the source. How to set jumping by default?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

When I click on a file in a default changelist it shows me diff instead of jumping to the source. How to set jumping by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that you need to go to `Commit` toolwidnow, then click on **Gear** icon (right upper corner of `Commit` toolwindow) -> **Show On Double-click** -> **Source**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find how that guy recommended it, so I just pressed `ctrl + shift + A` and put **Show On Double** there, turn ON **show source on double-click** and it worked. Thanks, man!